# Prevent Text with background from expanding to maxWidth

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `Text` with a background (which is just a coloured bubble), and I'm trying to restrict its `maxWidth` to some width, say `200` for this example.

I'm running into a problem with `.frame(..., maxWidth: ...)`.

#### Expected Behvaiour

[image]

- smaller messages are as big as they need to be
- larger messages will have a width up to the `maxWidth` and will wrap without text being truncated

#### Actual Behaviour

- no matter in which order the `.background()` and `.frame()` modifiers are applied, the `Text` is always drawn as what I have set the `maxWidth` to be.

In more detail:
**Applying the `.background()` before the `.frame(maxWidth: 200)`:**

```swift
Text(...)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    .background(
        Rectangle()               
    )
                    
    .frame(maxWidth: 200)
```

[image]

This results in the frame of all the `Text`s being of width 200 - which I'm not understanding. I understand that the background is applied before, so the background size is correct, but why does the frame become the maximum width? Am I misunderstanding how the `maxWidth:`  frame works?

This behaviour is the exact same without the `.fixedSize()` modifier, as all that does is prevent the text from truncating into `...`

**Applying the `.background()` after the `.frame(maxWidth: 200)`:**

```swift
Text(...)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    .frame(maxWidth: 200)

    .background(
        Rectangle()               
    )
```

[image]

This shows the behaviour again, but this time with the background also affected by the frame. The modifier stacking behaviour is expected, but again, I'm not sure why the Text is expanding to the `maxWidth`.

For further information, these `Text`s are within an `HStack` with a `Spacer()` on the left side. The `HStack`s are within a larger `VStack`+`ScrollView`.
Removing the `HStack`, `Spacer()` or the `ScrollView/VStack` does not change this behaviour.

I have tried giving it a `minWidth` and applying other modifiers to no avail. Any help is appreciated, as I feel that I'm missing something very obvious!

Thanks.

Edit: greater concision.

Comment: Do you expect UI as on first image?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, the expected UI should be that the Text bubbles are as big as they need to be (not all expanding to the max width). They should all be aligned to the right with the spacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `.frame(maxWidth:)` to the `VStack`, not to each `Text`.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                MyText(text: "111")
                MyText(text: "111")
            }
            MyText(text: "222222222")
            MyText(text: "3333333333333")
            MyText(text: "Long long long long long long long long long long text")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 200) // << there
    }
    
    struct MyText: View {
        var text: String
        
        var body: some View {
            Text(text)
                .padding(6)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.yellow)
                )
                .border(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

The blue border represents the actual `Text` frame sizes.
[image: Preview]

If you need a trailing alignment, then you should to set it in `VStack(alignment: .trailing)`.
[image: Preview2]

If you also need a trailing alignment inside `Text` frame, you can apply `.multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)` to `Text`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. I need to go touch up on my understanding of how modifiers work with Text!